# Get width of related components in Angular2

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-components

I have a parent component that contains a few child components.

The parent component is sort of behaving as the UI manager in charge of dimensions which will pass the information to the child components.

The problem is two of these sub components have dynamic widths, while the rest have fixed sizes. The information is passed through directives to the child components, though as the components are being initialized/created the widths are fetched and passed on, this causes errors in debug mode since the first time around a width was fetched that is different than the second round when the rest of the components are created.

I can't change the design at this time and have to live with a parent component in charge of the UI.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

The code is pretty simple:

parent component (view):

```
 <div #comp1Wrapper>
     <child-comp1 [dimentions]="comp1Dimentions"></child-comp1>
 </div>
 <div #comp2Wrapper>
     <child-comp2 [dimentions]="comp2Dimentions"></child-comp2>
 </div>
```

Parent component:

```
@ViewChild(comp1Dimentions) private m_comp1Wrapper: ElementRef;
@ViewChild(comp2Dimentions) private m_comp2Wrapper: ElementRef;
get comp1Dimentions:any
{
     return {x: m_comp1Wrapper.nativeElement.width, y: something};
}
get comp2Dimentions:any
{
     return {x: m_comp2Wrapper.nativeElement.width, y: something};
}
```

I can write the child code too but it don't think it adds any value.
And here's the error:
XCEPTION: Error in 'comp-name' class comp-class- inline template:36:46 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '682x55'. Current value: '634x55'.

Comment: Please post the code and exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something else down the road but first binding to getters or methods that return a new instance every time they are called like in the code below is usually not working will in Angular2 (4)

```ts
get comp1Dimentions:any
{
     return {x: m_comp1Wrapper.nativeElement.width, y: something};
     // returns a new instance every time it's called
}
get comp2Dimentions:any
{
     return {x: m_comp2Wrapper.nativeElement.width, y: something};
     // returns a new instance every time it's called
}
```

A better approach is to use a field where you assign the value and bind the view to

```ts
comp1Dimension:any = {x: 0, y: something};
comp2Dimentions:any = {x: 0, y: something};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.updateDimentions();
}
```

and use some event to update the object containing the dimension values

```ts
@HostBinding('window:resize') // just one option
updateDimentions() {
  this.comp1Dimension.x = m_comp1Wrapper.nativeElement.width;
  this.comp2Dimentions.x = m_comp2Wrapper.nativeElement.width;
}

ngDoCheck() { // another option
  this.updateDimentions();
}
```

If you only assign a new object when the current value is actually different than the old value, it's fine to assign a new object instance instead of updating the existing object.

Angular2 does a 2nd change detection run in devMode after the regular one to check that the model has stabilized. Angular2 change detection doesn't check object properties equality, it only checks object identity. Your code always returns a new object instance and Angular2 therefore never concludes that the with didn't actually change.